# Wrap iframe with a custom div

Tags: javascript, summernote

I'm using summernote with video plugin and would like to wrap the video iframe with a custom div. It is possible?

There is a method to detect when a content is inserted?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @NewToJS Not yet. This is my first time with Summernote. I'm looking for a solution in the documentation. Is there any methor to detect when a content is added?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this SO answer: [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

In summary,

1. The contents of the `iframe` must be from the same domain as your website, or you will be limited due to the same origin policy.
2. If you have `jQuery`, you can access the contents of an `iframe` like so (where `iframeid` is the `id` property of the `iframe` element:

   `$("#iframeid").contents().find("#someDiv")`
3. If you don't have `jQuery`, you can try:

   `myiframe.contentWindow.document`

   where `myiframe` is the target `iframe` DOM element.

Addendum: You may want to check if the `iframe` has loaded. With `jQuery`:

```
$("#iframeid").ready(function () {
  //Do stuff in here
});
```